# Setting up CW alert for disk usage using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

Been searching for a while but without any luck.

Im trying to setup a CW alert for disk usage percent using terraform but I am getting insufficient data.

I have set up the alert like this:

```
    resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "ec2_disk_space" {
    for_each            = local.disk_space_path
    alarm_name          = "ec2_disk_space_${each.key}"
    comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    metric_name         = "disk_used_percent"
    namespace           = "CloudWatchCustomMetrics"
    period              = "600"
    evaluation_periods  = "1"
    statistic           = "Average"
    threshold           = "90"
    alarm_description   = "The disk space on path ${each.key} average percentage is over 90% for the last 10 minutes"
    actions_enabled     = "true"
    treat_missing_data  = "ignore"
    alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.aws-notification-terraform.arn]
    ok_actions          = [aws_sns_topic.aws-notification-terraform.arn]
    dimensions = {
      InstanceId    = var.instance_ids
      path          = each.key
    }
  }
```

In which "path" goes trough couple of paths that I collect metric about using the CWAgent.
And the instanceID is a variable for my instance ID.

I get the alert created in the CloudWatch alarms dashboard, but its always shows insufficient data.
I have tried providing it with more info like "InstanceType" and "ami". Same error stays.

Comment: Have you installed the CloudWatch agent on the corresponding EC2 instances: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html?

Comment: I did, other metrics are working

Comment: Could you please check if the metrics are getting reported for `disk_used_percent`  in the cloudwatch console?

Comment: @Abhinaya They are working, if I configure it manually it works as intended

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it turns out that,
I just needed to provide the whole list of dimensions for it to recognize. I was providing it with only some of them.
something like that:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "ec2_disk_space" {
  alarm_name          = "ec2_disk_space"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  metric_name         = "disk_used_percent"
  namespace           = "CloudWatchCustomMetrics"
  period              = "600"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "90"
  alarm_description   = "The disk space average precetage is over 90% for the last 10 minutes"
  actions_enabled     = "true"
  treat_missing_data  = "ignore"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.aws-notification-terraform.arn]
  ok_actions          = [aws_sns_topic.aws-notification-terraform.arn]
  dimensions = {
    InstanceId   = var.instance_ids
    ImageId      = "ami-"
    InstanceType = "r5.large"
    device       = "nvme"
    fstype       = "ext4"
    path         = "/"
  }
}
```